# pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: could not connect to ser ver: Connection timed out

Tags: tcp

When we follow the steps present in the link https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres-hot-standby#create-a-user-for-replication , at the step "Run the backup utility" facing issue that 
Is the server running on host "IP" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

when we gave command on standby as  'sudo -u postgres pg_basebackup -h [IP of master] -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main -U repuser -v -P --xlog-method=stream'

Is there any solution to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a rule to hba_conf for database 'replication' - seems its a special keyword here. Normal access 'all all' for 'repuser' in your case will not do it.